# how to call a function after dialog from $window.print() closes

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular JS and I am looking for a way so that I could execute a function after the print dialog closes. Is there a callback or promise that $window.print() returns?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.onafterprint` event.

> The afterprint event is raised after the user prints or aborts a print
>   dialog.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onafterprint

Comment: oh great.. but is there any angular way of handling the same ?

Comment: You can use `$window` or `$on`